# SVN Server with authentication via Github

Tags: authentication, svn, github

One of my users wants me to build an SVN server that uses a specific Github community for authentication.  Users who are members of this community should be able to use their Github credentials to access the SVN server.  I would expect the flow to be something like:

1. User sends encrypted username and password to the SVN server.
2. SVN server authenticates with Github.
3. If username and password are correct, verify that the user is a member of the correct community.
4. If username/password and community pass, allow access.

My first question would be, is this even possible?  If it is possible, could someone give me a little guidance?  If been reading the SVN book and checking the Github API but haven't come up with anything yet.

Comment: There's a certain irony in wanting to use svn at all once you've been exposed to git, and it's doubly delicious that one would want to do this with github. What's wrong with just using github?

Comment: They do use Github but have a need for an SVN server on the network.  The developer who requested this server says it won't be used often but, when it is used, they need it to be on the LAN and would like for everyone who is a member of our Github community to be able to use their Github credentials.

Comment: This seems fairly difficult to achieve.  Can you alternatively use a locally hosted git server?  Setting up authentication for that would be a lot easier (since, last I checked you can retrieve any users public SSH keys from github).